# Column 'artistname' does not belong to table on C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, ado.net

Hello I'm having a problem with my program on C#, I'm trying to save the data artist name in my datable and I'm getting this error message

```
"Column 'artistname' does not belong to table on C#"
```

How can I fix it?

Here is a screen shot from my database:
[image]

And here is the code

```
private string artistName;        
public string artistname
{
    get
    {
        return artistName;
    }
    set
    {
        artistName = value;
    }
}

clsDataConduit track = new clsDataConduit();
track.Execute("sporc_tbltrack_GetAll");
track.NewRecord["artistname"] = artistName;
```

Comment: You need to change the case of the property name you have because C# is case sensitive. See my answer below.

Comment: What do clsDataConduit and sporc_tbltrack_GetAll look like? artistname isn't in one of there despite what the SQL table has in it: you aren'0t accessing the table direrctly

Comment: The error message does not relate to the SQL table, but to the datatable. Are you sure your select clause includes that field?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the stored proc sporc_tbltrack_GetAll [at least I assume it's a stored proc, and not a cross between a spoon and a fork - a sporc ;-)]. Also, where does the save happen?

Comment: There seems too much bogus code here. Specifically, what is `track.NewRecord`?

Comment: Your naming convention is very strange. `artistName` as the field and `artistname` as the property. It should be `artistName` as the field and `ArtistName` as the property. Or just use an auto property.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Personally I'd say you should never have two members whose name only differs in case. Sure, its allowed but its a recipe for confusion...

Comment: @Chris This naming convention is pretty common in C#. And once you get used to it, separating indentifiers by the casing of the *first* letter becomes pretty easy. Personally I like prefixing my fields with an underscore, but many consider that ugly and prefer plain camelCase.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Really? Gosh, I'd never come across it before and thought that it was considered bad practice. I guess when its properties and their backers its not too bad and its not like having two separate public members differing just by case. :) I go for the underscore too. Gives more of an impression of something not to be messed with unless you're sure. :)

Comment: I just realised that nobody else has asked the obvious question of where exactly you got that message, whether there was a stack trace and exactly which line of code it is pointing at. Also was the error message associated with an exception of some kind?

Comment: Did you really get "... on C#" in your error message?? Anyway, we need more info on clsDataConduit class and sporc_tbltrack_GetAll sp.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is the right name "sporc_tbltrack_GetAll"??? because I have seen in other post that you have the field artistname here "sporc_tblaristtable_GetAll"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379313/search-for-some-sql-commands-on-c-sharp

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE sporc_tbltrack_GetAll 
AS
SELECT * FROM tbltrack

Comment: try adding the field in place of *. try doing something like this  "Select artistname, trackname,.. from ....."

Answer (score 0):

There is a high possibility that there must be an error in the stored procedure, in case you are using one.

All the best!

Answer (score -2):

```
 private string artistName;        
 public string ArtistName
    {
        get
        {
            return artistName;
        }
        set
        {
            artistName = value;
        }

    }
clsDataConduit track = new clsDataConduit();
track.Execute("sporc_tbltrack_GetAll");
track.NewRecord["artistname"] = artistName;
```

Comment: @Azhar He's ok on the artistname Property, since he left is all lowercase for the Property, and camel cased it for the field.  So I don't think it's a case-sensitivity issue.

Comment: @Dave: Look closely I have changed the property name to be in Sentence case ... and I explained that in the comments just below the code.

Comment: there is not any problem with case sensitivity because it pass correctly the data see this screen shot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/831/screenshot20111206at304.png/

Comment: @George: Do you read the comments before adding your's in? I have mentioned that I missed the camel case!